# Windows defender not removing Program:Win32/Cayunamer.A!ml from system

Tags: windows, security, malware, malware-removal

My Windows firewall gives me security alert that my device is affected by Program:Win32/Cayunamer.A!ml. But when I try to remove it by selecting action as Remove, no change occurs. It loads for a time and the alert is back that my device is affected. Can anyone suggest me a way to remove this from my device without the help of 3rd party apps?

Thank You

Comment: Got the same warning before installing device driver (DriverMax suggested updated driver). It is a device driver, so it may be locked because it is in use. See details in antivirus where file is located/what it is named and find what device is using it. Uninstall that driver, then run scan and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated Windows 10 to the newest version?  And then got Windows Defender updated?

Microsoft will see it as a threat if everything is up to date.

This is a very new threat.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Program:Win32/Cayunamer.A!ml&ThreatID=274594

Be sure to look in the Defender Quarantine and it there, remove it before restarting.

You may also wish to try a scan with Malwarebytes free version.

Finally, if a virus cannot be removed, it is necessary at that point to back up the system and re-install Windows.

Comment: Yes everything is upto date

Comment: Do a Complete Full Scan with Defender.  Also you may need to try the free version of Malwarebytes.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded MalwareBytes and completed the scan and quarantined all the malware but to no avail. It still exists. Also Full Scan too detected it and when I tried to remove it , nothing happened

Comment: You now need to consider backing up and reinstalling Windows. That is the normal fix for a virus that cannot be removed.